# Django login authentication and session without user models and ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-users, django-login

For various reasons, I cannot use Django's ORM features. Instead I have to query into a database to check passwords instead of using models. I can already do that. But I can't figure out how to make a custom auth backend work with that.

[This doc page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) details how to set up a custom auth backend. However, I am unsure as to how it is still tracking whether a user is logged in.

The authenticate and validate functions seem to be returning a User Object. And session seems to be used to track logged in users. What I don't understand is how to make that work with a custom user class that doesn't use models. How am I supposed to get the session key? Why is it set  SESSION_KEY = '_auth_user_id' at the start of init.py? Does that get updated when user logs in? And What is session_auth_hash?

Request.user exists. But if I set it for one request, do all subsequent requests in that session refer to that user?

All I want to do is let a user login and logout after matching database credentials.